# Let $ g(z)=\frac{1+e^z}{1-e^z}$.Compute $|\exp{g(g(ir))|}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\frac{1+e^z}{1-e^z}$

Compute  $|e^{f(f(ir))|}$,
where $r\in R$ is such number that the function is defined.

I have no idea how to start with.
Tried something like this
$$\frac{1+e^z}{1-e^z}=-(\frac{-1-e^z}{1-e^z})=-(\frac{1-e^z}{1-e^z}-\frac{2}{1-e^z})=-1+\frac{2}{1-e^x}$$ and
$$|e^{f(f(ir))|}=\exp({-1+\frac{2}{1-e^{f(ir)}}})$$
But that lead quite nowhere.
Any tips and advices will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(z)=\frac{1+e^z}{1-e^z}$$

Note that $\tan(x) = \dfrac{e^{2iz} - 1}{i(e^{2iz}+1)}$, thus we have $f(ir) = \dfrac{i}{\tan(r/2)}$, or using $\cot(x) = \dfrac{1}{\tan(x)}$ we can simplify $f(ir) = i\cot(r/2)$.

We can apply this again to find $f(f(ir)) = f(i\cot(r/2)) = i\cot(\cot(r/2)/2).$

Finally, $\exp(i\cot(\cot(r/2)/2))$ is simply $\cos(\alpha) + i\sin(\alpha)$ where $\alpha = \cot(\cot(r/2)/2)$.

But more importantly, $|\exp(i\alpha)|$ for any real $\alpha$ is $1$, as $e^{i\alpha}$ lies on the unit circle. Thus the answer is simply $1$.